# delphi 2010 and dbexpress firebird driver

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, dbexpress

I am getting to know the dbexpress firebird driver from Chau Chee-Yang (http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/)

I find it hard to install because there is very little information, I
succeded making a connection, but several questions arise: When using
the data explorer and I want to connect to the database sends me the
following error:

```
---------------------------  Database Explorer
---------------------------  The located assembly's manifest
definition does not match the
assembly reference. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x80131040)
---------------------------
```

When I want to generate the query in the command text of the sqldataset
delphi sends me the following error:

```
Cannot load metadata for
FIREBIRDCONNECTION. Add driver unit
to your uses (DbxInterBase or DbxDb2
or DbxMsSql or DBXMySQL or DbxOracle
or DbxSybaseASA or DbxSybaseASE).
```

I dont really know If I did something wrong installing the
driver, maybe I have to give the sql instructions like SelectSql.add
('select *.... in real time. Instead of the sqldataset I put a SQLTable
and I can see the data. I think something is wrong in not being able
to write sql instrcciones directly from the CommandText of the
sqldataset Any help well be appreciated

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this driver, but if you're using the Enterprise or Architect editions, they ship with their own dbExpress driver for Firebird.  It may work better in the data explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I also get that error in the data explorer.  There were some notes about this in the support forum.  It seemed like he had a fix, but it hasn't made it in yet.  Here's the link:

http://groups.google.com/group/dbxfirebird/browse_thread/thread/a99e9f7946abd67c

Comment: Thank´s a lot, are you having problems when you write your sql in the command text?

Comment: I've only used the components by creating them directly in code.  I haven't run into any problems, but I also haven't done anything too fancy, just basic queries.